# redirect_to method fails to work rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<script>
  function check()
  {
    <% if !user_signed_in? %>
    alert("Sign in to order");
    <%redirect_to :path=>new_user_session_path%>
    <% else %>
    <% if current_user.points < form.order_total.value %>
    <%redirect :path=>credits_path%>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  }
</script>
```

I have written this in orders new page. I have written this to respond to a onclick action. What am I doing wrong here? I have also tried

<% redirect_to new_user_sessions_path %> and similarly for the other one too. How should I change make that work?

The error I get is

```
undefined method `redirect_to'
```

Comment: Use like this: redirect_to "your path"

Comment: it still says undefined method `redirect_to'

Answer (score 2):

you can use `window.location` to redirect the user using javascript and use the path helpers to get the location via Rails. Sthing like this

```
   <script>
      function check()
      {
        <% if !user_signed_in? %>
           alert("Sign in to order");
           window.location = "<%= j new_user_session_path %>";
        <% elsif current_user.points < form.order_total.value %>
            window.location = "<%= j credits_path %>";
        <% end %>
      }
    </script>
```

Note that the Rails part is parsed before being sent to the client. So the if else statement will not be executed on client side.